# Infinite Product $\prod_{ n \in \mathbb Z \setminus \{ 0 \} } (1 - z/n) e^{z/n}$ holomorphic on $\mathbb C$

Tags: complex-analysis

In preparing for my exam on complex analysis, I want to show that the infinite product

\begin{align}
\prod_{ n \in \mathbb Z \setminus \{ 0 \} } (1 - z/n) e^{z/n}
\end{align}

is holomorphic on $\mathbb C$.
I suppose you would have to show that

\begin{align}
\sum_{ n \in \mathbb Z \setminus \{ 0 \} } |\ln(1 - z/n) + z/n|
\end{align}

converges.
BUT, I don't know how to.
Please help!

Comment: I think you need more.  Show it converges uniformly on compact sets.

Answer (score 1):

Hint: Consider the function $f(z)=\ln(1-z)+z$ and think about what you can say about $f$ near $0$.

More details are hidden below.

> $f$ is holomorphic in a neighborhood of $0$ with $f(0)=0$ and $f'(0)=0$.  It follows that $f(z)$ can be written as $z^2g(z)$ where $g$ is holomorphic in a neighborhood of $0$.  In particular, $f(z)$ is bounded near $0$ by $c|z|^2$ for some constant $c$.  So now the terms in your sum are bounded (for $n$ large) by $c|z|^2/n^2$ and so the sum converges since $\sum_n 1/n^2$ converges.  Moreover, this convergence will be uniform in $z$ as long as $z$ is bounded and so your product converges locally uniformly and thus the limit is holomorphic.

Comment: $\ln (1-z)$ is not an acceptable notation. Do you mean the principal branch?

Comment: I just followed the notation that OP used.  It's not totally precise, but it seems to me like a totally fine notation to use informally in this context.  Obviously we are talking about a branch of the logarithm near 1 with $\ln(1)=0$.